# how to classify the rows based on the certain amount of columns (delete the rows which have more column than the set one) in panda

Tags: python, pandas

Well, I have a very big data, in short, I can say I have 10K events (rows), and in each event, I have different stations (columns, maximum for example 30 stations), and I want to set the maximum amount of columns (e.g. 20 columns) and those events which have more than 20 columns be excluded,

my question is how can I find the rows (within 10K) which have more than 20 columns and then `drop()` them.

for example in the picture below, I want to set 7 stations (columns) as length, therefore the rows which have more than 7 stations should be deleted.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAUL4.png)

I do not know making the loop would be worked or not

```py
for i in range(7,10):
    if df.iloc[i]['station8','statoin9','station10']== True:
        print i,df.iloc[i]['station8','statoin9','station10']
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *dropping* rows that do have values in the extra columns, you can alternatively only *keep* the rows that have no values there.

Some test data (your example):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

value_counts = [7, 7, 10, 7, 7, 8, 9, 7, 9, 7]

df = pd.DataFrame([['x']*v + [np.nan]*(10-v) for v in value_counts],
                  columns=[f'Station{i}' for i in np.arange(10)+1],
                  index=np.arange(10)+1)
```

Result:

```py
   Station1 Station2 Station3  ... Station8 Station9 Station10
1         x        x        x  ...      NaN      NaN       NaN
2         x        x        x  ...      NaN      NaN       NaN
3         x        x        x  ...        x        x         x
4         x        x        x  ...      NaN      NaN       NaN
5         x        x        x  ...      NaN      NaN       NaN
6         x        x        x  ...        x      NaN       NaN
7         x        x        x  ...        x        x       NaN
8         x        x        x  ...      NaN      NaN       NaN
9         x        x        x  ...        x        x       NaN
10        x        x        x  ...      NaN      NaN       NaN
```

Now you can keep the rows that only contain `NaN` in the extra columns:

```py
columns_to_include = 7

df[df.iloc[:, columns_to_include:].isna().all(axis=1)]
```

Result:

```py
   Station1 Station2 Station3  ... Station8 Station9 Station10
1         x        x        x  ...      NaN      NaN       NaN
2         x        x        x  ...      NaN      NaN       NaN
4         x        x        x  ...      NaN      NaN       NaN
5         x        x        x  ...      NaN      NaN       NaN
8         x        x        x  ...      NaN      NaN       NaN
10        x        x        x  ...      NaN      NaN       NaN
```

Comment: the point is, if I just remove the extra columns, since all those data per rows are related together, i will face a missing data problems, therefore I want to first find the all the rows which have more than e.g. 100 columns and then drop them.